# Visualisation data as Hierarchical Graph according to most common element

Tags: python, graph, visualization

Hope you doing all well,

i want a graph that represent rows of DataFrame ' Hierarchical graph that add egdes between npdes appear together in the same row of the DataFrame '

And to do this , i use networkx , and that's the code :

```js
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_graph = data_cleaned.drop(['motif',  'index', 'motif_cleaned'], axis=1)

# Create an empty directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame and add edges to the graph
for _, row in data_graph.iterrows():
    values = row.dropna().values  # Get the non-NaN values in this row
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):
        G.add_edge(values[i], values[i + 1])  # Add edge to the graph

# Convert the directed graph to an undirected graph
H = G.to_undirected()

# Calculate the Jaccard distance between the neighbors of each node in the undirected graph
jac = nx.jaccard_coefficient(H)

# Create a new graph with the Jaccard distances as edge weights
D = nx.DiGraph()
for u, v, j in jac:
    if j > 0:
        D.add_edge(u, v, weight=1 - j)

# Filter the nodes that have non-NaN values
valid_nodes = [n for n in G.nodes() if pd.notna(n)]

# Count the frequency of each node
node_freq = {}
for node in valid_nodes:
    node_freq[node] = np.count_nonzero(data_graph.values.flatten() == node)

print(node_freq)  # Print the node frequency

# Draw the graph using the Kamada-Kawai layout algorithm
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(H, weight='weight', scale= 100)



nx.draw(G, pos=pos, labels={n: n for n in valid_nodes})

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and that's the output :

[image]

And that's tha DataFrame :

[image]

So, as you can see the output represent each row in DataFrame, BUT i want to organize the nodes in the graph according to its repetition in DataFrame,  start from the most common element in database. And i want the output something like this  :

[image]

Please anyone can help me. I will appreciate the help.
Thank in advance.